# Create a table that queries from a different table every 5 minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wish to create a table that will query a simple query from another table every 5 minutes and create a time-stamp and the result of the query.

So for example if my query will be 
    SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE

I will get results of

Time                result
1-1-2017 00:00:00     45
1-1-2017 00:05:00     65
1-1-2017 00:10:00     35

etc

Answer (score 0):

Use the [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) to execute a query like:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (timestamp,result) 
SELECT now(), (SELECT count(*) FROM...)
```

You can add other columns and customize at will.